# Как понять, какие данные не используются MS SQL и как их удалить?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

ВЫвел отчет по занятому месту на диске в MS SQL, по двум таблицам у меня много памяти не используется на диске, как понять, что это за данные не используются в таблицах. На картинке видно сколько места занято неиспользуемыми данными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такое может быть, если, например, удаляли много данных. Попробуйте сперва `ALTER INDEX ALL ON table REORGANIZE` (возможно не один раз).

Answer (score 0):

Нет, речь не о **данных**. Используются **данные** или нет, можете решить только вы. Тут показано **место** занятое таблицами на диске, но свободное от данных. Место всегда выделяется заранее с запасом. При удалении данных занятое место не освобождается. Это нормально.

Смотрите документацию.
[CREATE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=sqlpool) - параметр FILEGROWTH - на сколько будет увеличиваться БД.
[Shrink a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16) - БД можно сжать, но обычно это не рекомендуется.

[Considerations for the autogrow and autoshrink settings in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/considerations-autogrow-autoshrink).
[Space used by a table is not released](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/space-table-uses-not-released).
[Defragmenting SQL Server database disk drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/defragmenting-database-disk-drives).
И другие статьи в меню слева.

---

И обязательно обновите статистику после удаления большого объёма данных! [Statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver16). Это критически важно для высокой производительности СУБД. Часто к этому относятся пренебрежительно, что очень плохо.

---

Примечание: язык документации можно переключить на русский (или ещё какой) в левом нижнем углу. "Опытные пользователи ПК" ™ не догадываются до такого простого действия...